# Run linux executable in Windows using Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, cross-platform

Is there a way in Python that can call a subprocess that refers a linux executable in Windows ? If important, the executable is a GCC compiled c executable, but compiled in Ubuntu.

I also have WSL2 linux subsystem installed on my Windows 10, which I can easily create a Python script inside to achieve this, however this question is born of curiosity. I would like to call the Python script in Windows itself.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The solution might include using Linux subsystem calls from Python in Windows, however I don't have knowledge about how.

Comment: Can't you do this with `os.system()` or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Ahmet I could if the exe was a Windows exe, however it is not. It's a linux application that doesn't end with the regular Windows `.exe`.

Comment: you cannot **natively** run linux executables on windows, its impossible.